# Sending data over a socket in Java at the zeroth nanosecond of a specific hour

Tags: java, spring

I want to send data over a socket in Java at 09:00:00.0000000000 nanoseconds. Unfortunately, with the following code, there is a delay 000219600 nanoseconds. How can I improve this?

```
@Scheduled(cron ="xxxxx") // trigger at 08.59.00.0000000000
    @Async
    public void triggerJob() {
        List<OmsOrder> omsOrderList = getOmsSmartOrders();

        if(isStarted || CollectionUtils.isEmpty(omsOrderList)) {
            return;
        }
        isStarted = true;
        List<EnterOrderRequestDto> enterOrderRequestDtoList = omsOrderList.stream().map(this::enterOrderRequestDto).collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<EnterOrderMessage> enterOrderMessageList = enterOrderRequestDtoList.stream().map(OmsOrderMapper::toEnterOrderMessage).collect(Collectors.toList());

        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        LocalDateTime openingAuction = LocalDateTime.of(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDayOfMonth(), 9,0);
        do {
        } while (LocalDateTime.now().isBefore(openingAuction));

  
            log.info("oms smart order triggered {}", LocalDateTime.now() );
            send(omsOrderList.get(0));
        
        isStarted = false;
    }
```

log:
oms smart order triggered 2023-12-30T09:00:00.000219600

Comment: you probably need `System.nanoTime()`

Comment: You can’t, unless you have (1) a real-time operating system and (2) a real-time implementation of Java that can make such a guarantee.

Comment: Well, you're doing some work before the log statement. What about logging at the beginning of the method? Also I'm not sure you can have nanoseconds precision when scheduling in Java, what scheduler are you using?

Comment: By the way, `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use here. Lacking the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, that class cannot represent a moment, is not a specific point on the timeline. To track a moment, use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Scheduling something for nanosecond precision is not remotely going to be practical.  I'd be surprised if any average CPU could do it at all.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with computer clocks and scheduling. Most notable are:

1. Clocks have limited precision. There is a smallest value all time values are multiple of, usually millisecond or nanosecond.
2. Clocks have limited resolution. Even if clock is able to report values accurate to nanosecond it doesn't mean it changes its reported value every "live" nanosecond.
3. If a thread execution is paused (via `sleep()` or other means) there is a limit how short this duration can be.
4. Querying clock also takes time
5. Clocks depend on underlying system and may vary heavily in behaviour.

So, you definitely cannot guarantee any precise scheduling. However, you can make it close enough for practical needs. Most accurate things available in Java are `System.nanoTime()` for querying time and `Thread.onSpinWait()` for busy waiting. However, there is a problem - `System.nanoTime()` is not necessarily aligned with `LocalDateTime.now()`, so it might be tricky. Here's how it might look

```
  // next call suffers from problems 1 and 2 on now variable
  busyWaitUntil(System.nanoTime() + now.until(openingAuction, ChronoUnit.NANOS));
  // ...
  public void busyWaitUntil(long nanos) {
    while (System.nanoTime() < nanos) {
      Thread.onSpinWait();
    }
  }
```